# QFT/QM on loop space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, wilson-loop

I am reading "Gauging What's Real" by Richard Healey and the author argues for formulating electrodynamics/QED on loop space/the holonomy group, so that the real objects described by the theory are the Wilson Loops or Dirac phase factors ${ e }^{ \frac { ie }{ \hbar  } \oint _{ \gamma  }^{  }{ { A }_{ \mu  }d{ x }^{ \mu  } }  }$.

I was wondering if it is possible to formulate Quantum Field Theory (or maybe even Quantum Mechanics) on loop spaces, so that the quantum field/ wave functions take loops as arguments.  (I am especially interested if one could formulate Quantum Mechanics in this way).

Comment: You can pick up any book on loop quantum gravity, which would have an introduction on loop representation of gauge theories.

Answer (score 6):

Quantum mechanics on the loop space is a rather convenient way to think about 1+1d sigma models. It's one way to understand the Kac-Moody symmetry of WZW CFTs for example, whose field is a map from spacetime to a Lie group. Witten famously used [SUSY quantum mechanics on loop space](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214437492) to give a formulation of Floer theory of symplectic manifolds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The paper seems quite technical. Is there an easy way to write e.g. a wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ depending on space and time coordinates as a wave function depending on" loop coordinates" $\Psi (\gamma , t)$